# WebService (Soap) with Delphi XE2 complex responses

Tags: delphi, soap

I am trying to create a WebService with Delphi, the simple part is working for example a simple response.

But my issue is how to make it multi array/multi level response

For example :

i want to get something like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:RoommatikIntf-IRoommatik">
      <NS1:GetAllRoomTypeRatesResponse xmlns:NS2="urn:RoommatikIntf">
         <NS2:RoomTypeRate id="1" xsi:type="NS2:RoomTypeRate">
            <NS2:RoomType id="2" xsi:type="NS2:RoomType">
               <Id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Id>
               <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Test0</Name>
            </NS2:RoomType>
            <Price xsi:type="xsd:double">100.2</Price>
         </NS2:RoomTypeRate>
      </NS1:GetAllRoomTypeRatesResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

RoomType is inside the RoomTypeRate tag.

But at the moment all i get is literally this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:RoommatikIntf-IRoommatik">
      <NS1:GetAllRoomTypeRatesResponse xmlns:NS2="urn:RoommatikIntf">
         <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="NS2:RoomTypeRate[1]">
            <item href="#1"/>
         </return>
         <NS2:RoomTypeRate id="1" xsi:type="NS2:RoomTypeRate">
            <RoomType href="#2"/>
            <Price xsi:type="xsd:double">100.2</Price>
         </NS2:RoomTypeRate>
         <NS2:RoomType id="2" xsi:type="NS2:RoomType">
            <Id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Id>
            <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Test0</Name>
         </NS2:RoomType>
      </NS1:GetAllRoomTypeRatesResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

the Intf file is:

```
unit RoommatikIntf;

interface

uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_UNBD = $0002;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_REF  = $0080;

type

  RoomType = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FId: Integer;
    FName_: string;
  published
    property Id:          Integer  read FId write FId;
    property Name:        string   read FName_ write FName_;
  end;
  RoomTypeRate2 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FRoomType : String;
  published
    property RoomType: String Read FRoomType write FRoomType;
  end;

  RoomTypeRate = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FRoomType: RoomType;
    FPrice: Double;
  published
    property RoomType:     RoomType      Index (IS_OPTN) read FRoomType write FRoomType;
    property Price:        Double        read FPrice write FPrice;
  end;

  ArrayOfRoomTypeRate = array of RoomTypeRate;

  { Invokable interfaces must derive from IInvokable }
  IRoommatik = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{DB8CC9DF-B105-4CCF-9CE5-C45EBCF4CF43}']

    { Methods of Invokable interface must not use the default }
    { calling convention; stdcall is recommended }
    function GetDateTime: TXSDateTime; stdcall;
    function GetAllRoomTypeRates: ArrayOfRoomTypeRate; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

initialization
  { Invokable interfaces must be registered }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IRoommatik));


end.
```

and Impl file is :

```
unit RoommatikImpl;

interface

uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns, RoommatikIntf, DateUtils, SysUtils;

type

  { TRoommatik }
  TRoommatik = class(TInvokableClass, IRoommatik)
  public
    function GetAllRoomTypeRates: ArrayOfRoomTypeRate; stdcall;
    function GetDateTime: TXSDateTime; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

function TRoommatik.GetDateTime: TXSDateTime; stdcall;
var
  DateTime : TXSDateTime;
begin
  DateTime := TXSDateTime.Create;
  DateTime.AsDateTime := now+1;
  Result := DateTime;
end;

function TRoommatik.GetAllRoomTypeRates: ArrayOfRoomTypeRate; stdcall;
Var
  RoomArray : ArrayOfRoomTypeRate;
begin
  RoomArray := ArrayOfRoomTypeRate.Create();
  SetLength(RoomArray, 1);
  RoomArray[0] := RoomTypeRate.Create;
  RoomArray[0].RoomType := RoomType.Create;
  RoomArray[0].RoomType.Id := 1;
  RoomArray[0].RoomType.Name := 'Test0';
  RoomArray[0].Price    := 100.20;

  Result := RoomArray;
end;



initialization
{ Invokable classes must be registered }
   InvRegistry.RegisterInvokableClass(TRoommatik);
end.
```

Please point me in the right direction as i find no info on how to make this correctly.

Thank you in regards.

Comment: Have you looked at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024957/delphi-soap-arrays-problem)?

Comment: @WillovanderMerwe Thanks for the link, no i havent seen that before, will have a look and see if it gives me any more info.